# Construct grammar for the following languages

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, computation-theory

I just took my midterm but couldn't answer this question.

Construct grammar for the following languages
L={(a* ba* ba*)*}

Comment: Uhm - isn't that the grammar you have there?

Answer (score 0):

The outermost rule is Kleene closure,  `*`. What's inside parentheses is a language unto itself. This suggests the following productions for our grammar:

```
S := e
S := SL
```

Here, `e` is the empty string and `L` is the start symbol for a grammar generating the language corresponding to the regular expression inside the parentheses.

Now our language is that which begins with any number of `a`s, followed by a `b`, followed by any number of `a`s, followed by a `b`, followed by any number of `a`s. We can first define "any number of `a`s":

```
A := e
A := Aa
```

And then the definition of `L` is straightforward:

```
L := AbAbA
```

The complete grammar is therefore:

```
S := e
S := SL
L := AbAbA
A := e
A := Aa
```